# Does GitHub allow you to create multiple (2) personal accounts?

Tags: github, account

There is nothing in the GitHub guidelines, as far as I can see, that prevents people from making multiple personal accounts. I would like to create a "more serious" account and move my serious projects there, and keep the trash on a side-account.

The problem is that I used to have two accounts a few years ago, and GitHub actually banned both accounts due to that. They told me that "you are only allowed to have 1 account". I had to petition their support to reopen my main account. But it seems like they've changed their stance now, because I can't find any wording that prevents multiple accounts anymore.

I am Googling for the term `multiple accounts site:help.github.com` and the pages that come up seem to indicate that it's allowed these days.

For example, https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/merging-multiple-user-accounts says "We recommend using only one user account to manage both personal and professional repositories", which *sounds* like they accept multiple accounts too.

Does anyone know? Perhaps some of you have multiple accounts successfully!

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea, how about creating an Organization instead, and keeping your important stuff there?

Comment: @emix Hmm that's not a bad idea... I'll consider that. Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be better to create an Organization instead and keep your important projects there. It's always much easier to have a single account in terms on maintainability.

For instance: in BitBucket you cannot have your single public key attached to two different accounts.

Comment: Thanks, that's actually a brilliant solution I hadn't thought about. It means I can just have a single key on the computer, which is much easier to manage. But can still have a clean organization for the serious projects! This is smart. I'm accepting this answer! PS: If someone else knows if _actual_ multi-accounts are allowed, feel free to answer that too.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 7):

I found the actual answer in the Terms of Service:

https://help.github.com/en/github/site-policy/github-terms-of-service

## "One person or legal entity may maintain no more than *one* free Account (if you choose to control a machine account as well, that's fine, but it can only be used for running a machine)."

So that's why they banned me all those years ago. You're only allowed to have 1 account if you aren't a paying user.

But I will accept @emix answer, since he was the first to suggest the smart solution of making an Organization for my serious projects!

Answer (score 1):

You can create New organisations linked to your main personal account.